# Removing HTML tags and converting special characters in rss feed from Facebook

Tags: android, html, facebook, character-encoding, rss

I'm getting RSS feed from a Facebook page in my Android app.

The URL I'm using to getting the information is the following:
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=100407896713917

However, this RSS feed returns me some HTML tags when it has images, for instance. For me, the images are not important, I would like to get only the text content.

Is it possible to ignore this HTML tags and get only the text?

Another question, some special characters are being converted to others.. but I guess it is not problem when I'm downloading the info, because if I open the URL above in my browser, these weird characters also appears.

Is there a way to convert the weird characters to the normals one? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing a more mechanic logic. Dunno if there is a better solution, but what I did was converting each character acording to its code (I don't know the kind of code RSS uses for special characters). Here's my logic

```
html = i.getDescription(); // some tag of rss feed
html = html.replaceAll("<(.*?)\\>"," ");//Removes all items in brackets
html = html.replaceAll("<(.*?)\\\n"," ");//Must be undeneath
html = html.replaceFirst("(.*?)\\>", " ");//Removes any connected item to the last bracket
html = html.replaceAll("&nbsp;"," ");
html = html.replaceAll("&amp;"," ");
html = html.replaceAll("&quot;","'");
html = html.replaceAll("&#xe7;","ç");
html = html.replaceAll("&#xe3;","ã");
html = html.replaceAll("&#xf3;","ó");
html = html.replaceAll("&#xe1;","á");
html = html.replaceAll("&#xe9;","é");
html = html.replaceAll("&#xed;","í");
html = html.replaceAll("&#xea;","ê");
html = html.replaceAll("&#xc9;","É");
```

with this logic, I'm also removing HTML tags